# Slotted bead head on non-jig hook

Tags: fly-tying

I'm ordering beadheads for fly tying, and am thinking about getting slotted beadheads to use on jig hooks. The main application will be nymphs to be used as the point fly in a two or three nymph setup.

Since the producer I'm buying from offers those wholesale, I wonder if I can just buy a big pack of each size and colour that I need, and use them on other hook types as well. Has anyone tried it? Would it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, it seems to work. The trick is to use the lead/lead-free wire wraps to hold the bead in place. You can stick a few of the wraps inside the bead and turn the slot downwards. A drop of zap-a-gap on the shank, just behind the eye of the hook helps to hold it all in place.
[image]